# Gnome 45 / Ubuntu 23.10 focusing windows I didn't click

Tags: gnome, window-management

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 / Gnome 45. It appears that now when I click on an unfocused window that I have snapped to one side of the screen, it automatically focuses another window that is open, causing it to cover whatever it was I actually wanted to see on the other side of the screen. How can I disable this behavior? I guess I can see myself wanting the other window to also pop up if I have selected it to fill the other half of the screen, but it just seems to be a random different window that I happen to have snapped to the other side of the screen at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under the Settings app > Ubuntu Desktop > Enhanced Tiling section. It sounds like you're talking about the "Tile Groups" feature, so check the description of how that feature is intended to work:

[image: Enhanced Tiling section of Ubuntu Desktop settings in Ubuntu 23.10]

You may just wish to disable it, or file a bug report if it's not working "as advertised".